# How can I conduct an experiment on the buring power of a 2 inch cubic block of wood?

Tags: mass, volume

I'm trying to help my son put together a science project and the hypothesis that we've come up with is this:

If you take cubes of wood of the same volume (say 2 inches cubed) and start them burning with the same amount of heat over a 1 liter of water, that those woods with a higher density of mass will produce a greater increase in the temperature of the water.

But what I am struggling with is can I determine the MASS first or density? Or can I only determine the volume by water displacement or something?

Basically is there a way to determine the mass/density in some type of units before I burn each piece of wood?

Comment: Mass is needed here. But have you considered you'll be losing a lot of heat that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cut your wood samples into accurate cubes. Measuring the cubes then lets you calculate their volume. Then weigh each cube. Now you can calculate their density.

Assuming the wood is dry, the amount of chemical potential energy contained in each cube is proportional to the mass of the cube. Since different woods have different densities, a 2 inch cube of eastern hard maple (high density) will contain more energy than an identical cube cut from western cedar (low density).

Burning the wood samples to heat water out in the open will transfer only a fraction of the heat released by burning the wood into the water, and once warm, that water will be continually losing its heat to its surroundings. This will make it difficult for you to use the heating-water technique to measure the "heat content" of your fuel. Chemists and engineers use (among other things) a device called a bomb calorimeter to make these sorts of measurements accurately.

Comment: Awesome! will there be enough of a temp difference to measure with a laser thermometer?

Comment: probably not. the thing to do would be to stick a thermometer into the water and measure it every 30 seconds, and make a chart like that for each type of wood.

Answer (score 0):

Mass is a measure of the amount of wood. Density is a measure of how much mass is in a block of a given size.

Oak is denser than balsa wood. Given two same-size blocks, an oak block weighs more. But a big block of balsa can have more mass and outweigh a small block of oak.

Keep in mind that wood fresh from a tree is denser than dried wood. Fresh wood has a lot of water in it. Dried wood does not.

Fresh wood is not as good at heating because the water in it produces no heat. Water in a burning piece of wood take heat that could have gone into heating your experiment.